# How to modify a string WHILE input in C language, using getche, C language?

Tags: c, string, backspace

I have written a code for searching a string among a group of strings but unlike we have to enter entire string before search, this code sorts out matching strings along with us entering each letter, like in Google search. But I don't know how to backspace string entry as it accepts string character by character.
C language only! Run the code once to understand better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char string[10];
    char s[5][10];
    int i, j, k;
    int e[5];
    char g;

    printf("\nEnter 5 Strings\n");

    //Enter 5 to search from
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d. ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", &s[i]);
        e[i]=1;
    }

    j=0;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\nResults: ");
        for(k=0;k<5;k++)
        {
            if(e[k]==1) //String displays if not striked by Input
                printf("\n%s", s[k]);
        }

        printf("\n\nEnter Search String: ");
        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            printf("%c", string[i]);
        }
        g = getche(); // Character Input
        string[j]=g;  // Character stored in string to compare
        for(k=0;k<5;k++)
        {
            if(strncmp(string, s[k], j+1)!=0)
                e[k]=0; //Used so if character doesn't match, string 
                          eliminates
        }
        j++;

    }while(g!='\r');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `prog.c:(.text.startup+0x111): undefined reference to \`getche'`

Comment: uhh what? @melpomene

Comment: That's the error I get when compiling your program.

Comment: Maybe console issue @melpomene. What are you using?

Comment: I ran it on http://ideone.com/.